# Последовательность условий в тесте

Tags: jquery

Как сделать так, что бы условия выполнялись не одно за другим, а в нужной последовательности.

3 вопроса, 1 правильный ответ, если пользователь нажимает на правильный ответ, то он подсвечивается зелёным, если на неправильный, то он подсвечивается красным, а правильный ответ опять же зелёным.

Код привожу:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".wrong1").click(function() {
    $(".wrong1").addClass("red");
    $(".correct").addClass("green");
  });
});
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: #E12F52;
}
.green {
  background-color: #4CE12F;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
<p class="wrong1">Это не правильный ответ.</p>
<p class="correct">Правильный!</p>
<p class="wrong2">Это тоже неправильный ответ</p>
```

**UPDATE:**
Вариант разметки с несколькими вопросами

```
<div class="test">

    <p class="wrong">Это не правильный ответ.</p>
    <p class="correct">Правильный!</p>
    <p class="wrong">Это тоже неправильный ответ</p>

    <p class="correct">Правильный ответ</p>
    <p class="wrong">неправильный</p>
    <p class="wrong">Это тоже неправильный ответ</p>

</div>
```

Comment: не меняйте полностью вопрос, а дополняйте его для уточнения, как это сделал я

Comment: @Grundy да, извините, сейчас

Answer (score 2):

Стоит немного пересмотреть логику работы:

> если пользователь нажимает на правильный ответ, то он подсвечивается зелёным, если на неправильный, то он подсвечивается красным, а правильный ответ опять же зелёным.

То есть, правильный ответ подсвечивается всегда, а неправильный только если его выбрали.

Таким образом можно определить класс `show` который при применении вместе с `wrong` - выставит красный свет, а при применении вместе с `correct` - зеленый

```
.wrong.show {
  background-color: #E12F52;
}
.correct.show {
  background-color: #4CE12F;
}
```

Теперь осталось только добавить этот класс к элементу по которому кликнули и к элементу с правильным ответом.

Пример:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p").click(function() {
    $(".correct").add(this).addClass("show");
  });
});
```

```css
.wrong.show {
  background-color: #E12F52;
}
.correct.show {
  background-color: #4CE12F;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="wrong">Это не правильный ответ.</p>
<p class="correct">Правильный!</p>
<p class="wrong">Это тоже неправильный ответ</p>
```

**UPDATE:**

Для случая нескольких вопросов вместо разметки когда все вопросы находятся в одном контейнере, как сейчас

```
<div class="test">

    <p class="wrong">Это не правильный ответ.</p>
    <p class="correct">Правильный!</p>
    <p class="wrong">Это тоже неправильный ответ</p>

    <p class="correct">Правильный ответ</p>
    <p class="wrong">неправильный</p>
    <p class="wrong">Это тоже неправильный ответ</p>

</div>
```

Каждый вопрос нужно поместить в свой собственный, например так

```
<div class="question">

    <p class="wrong">Это не правильный ответ.</p>
    <p class="correct">Правильный!</p>
    <p class="wrong">Это тоже неправильный ответ</p>
</div>
<div class="question">
    <p class="correct">Правильный ответ</p>
    <p class="wrong">неправильный</p>
    <p class="wrong">Это тоже неправильный ответ</p>

</div>
```

Таким образом можно будет разделить в каких вопросах надо подсвечивать ответы, а в каких нет.

Кроме того следует немного изменить яваскрипт, так как селектор `$(".correct")`, как уже было замечено, выбирает **все** элементы на странице с эти классом.

Изменить можно например так: взять родителя элемента по которому кликнули, это будет контейнер, и в нем найти элемент с нужным классом.

```
$(this).parent() // берем родителя
       .find('.correct') // берем правильный ответ
       .add(this).addClass("show"); // далее как уже было.
```

Пример:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p").click(function() {
    $(this).parent()
           .find(".correct")
           .add(this).addClass("show");
  });
});
```

```css
.wrong.show {
  background-color: #E12F52;
}
.correct.show {
  background-color: #4CE12F;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question">
  <p class="wrong">Это не правильный ответ.</p>
  <p class="correct">Правильный!</p>
  <p class="wrong">Это тоже неправильный ответ</p>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <p class="correct">Правильный ответ</p>
  <p class="wrong">неправильный</p>
  <p class="wrong">Это тоже неправильный ответ</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы очень помогли

Comment: подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, что бы если у меня было больше одного вопроса, то когда я нажимаю, допустим, на правильный ответ в первом вопросе, то во втором и последующих вопросах правильные ответы бы не подсвечивались?

Comment: @Alex, зависит от разметки, добавьте в вопрос разметку с несколькими вопросами и я обновлю ответ

Comment: изменил верстку в начальном примере с кодом, посмотрите, пожалуйста

Comment: или нужно обязательно менять классы во втором вопросе, иначе не выйдет?

Comment: @Alex, обновил ответ.

Comment: спасибо Вам огромное, вы мне очень помогли, теперь буду знать, как это правильно делать, спасибо

Comment: @Alex, я отклонил вашу правку, так как это не улучшало ответ. Лучше задайте еще [один **отдельный** вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: @Alex - обратите внимание на знак "галочка" слева от ответа. Если Вы хотите, чтобы Вам продолжали отвечать в будущем, отмечайте ответ, который Вы считаете правильным, щелчком по этотому знаку.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы вообще так не делал, а осуществлял бы аякс запросы на список вопросов с их id, а при выборе варианта, опять аякс запрос для проверки правильно выбранного варианта. А так получается что всегда можно подсмотреть правильный ответ)